# use argument as object property in angular

Tags: angular

Is there any way to convert string as object property in angular? eg:

```
getErrorMessage(error_type) {
    return this.userForm.controls.{error_type}.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
}

getErrorMesssage('email');
```

The function should work something like

```
return this.userForm.controls.email.hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
```

Comment: `return this.userForm.controls[error_type].hasError('required')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
getErrorMessage(error_type) {
  return this.userForm.controls[error_type].hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
}
```

Square brackets, not curly.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `get()` function:

```
getErrorMessage(controlName: string) {
    return this.userForm.get(controlName).hasError('required') ? 'You must enter a value' : '';
}
```

The only thing is that you want to pass the control name, not the error type, what I can see from your variable naming.

Answer (score 0):

In a general way, you can access object properties using bracket notation:

```js
const thing = { email: 'foo@bar.com };
console.log(thing['email']); // prints 'foo@bar.com'
```